# XMLSecurityConfigurationException: NAMESPACE_ERR with WS-Security on JBoss EAP 7.2.x

Tags: cxf, ws-security, jboss-eap-7, wss4j

We are migrating some applications from JBoss EAP 7.1.x to JBoss EAP 7.2.x.

A JAX-WS endpoint is deployed on a JBoss 7.2.x in standalone mode, using standalone-full.xml. This endpoint is secured with WS-Security, and its policies are declared in the wsdl.

When a request is sent to this endpoint by a client, an error message is received, informing that those policies cannot be satisfied.

```xml
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">
These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportBinding
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportToken
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}HttpsToken
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}AlgorithmSuite
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Basic128
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Layout
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Lax
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}IncludeTimestamp
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EndorsingSupportingTokens
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}X509Token
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}WssX509V3Token10
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Wss11
  </soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
      </soap:Fault>
```

Extract from server.log:

```
2019-10-09 09:41:31:633 FINE  [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader] (default task-1) Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor.<init>(WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor.java:92)
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JStaxOutInterceptor.<init>(PolicyBasedWSS4JStaxOutInterceptor.java:45)
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.WSSecurityInterceptorProvider.<init>(WSSecurityInterceptorProvider.java:65)
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader.registerProviders(WSSecurityPolicyLoader.java:300)
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader.<init>(WSSecurityPolicyLoader.java:108)
(…)
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.stax.ext.XMLSecurityConfigurationException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
Original Exception was org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
       at org.apache.xml.security.stax.config.Init.init(Init.java:89)
       at org.apache.wss4j.stax.setup.WSSec.<clinit>(WSSec.java:62)
       ... 106 more
```

Investigation shows that the issue occurs because an exception is raised during the parsing of wss-config.xml, located in xmlsec-2.1.2.redhat-00001.jar. This issue can be reproduced by calling this line in a managed environment, even out of the JAX-WS/CXF context:

```java
org.apache.xml.security.stax.config.Init.init(ClassLoaderUtils.getResource("wss/wss-config.xml", WSSec.class).toURI(), WSSec.class);
```

Line causing the exception in org.apache.xml.security.stax.config.Init from xmlsec-2.1.2.redhat-00001.jar:

```java
saxParser.parse(uri.toURL().toExternalForm(), new XIncludeHandler(unmarshallerHandler));
```

This error specifically occurs on a 7.2.x instance in a Redhat Environment, and it does not occur:

- On a 7.2.x instance installed in a Windows environment,
- On a 7.1.x instance installed in a Redhat or a Windows environment.

Config:

- OS: RedHat 7.7
- Kernel: 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64
- Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
- CXF version (from JBoss EAP 7.2.4): 3.2.9

Endpoint configuration:

```java
@WebContext(transportGuarantee = TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL, //
              urlPattern = "/MyEndpoint")
@EndpointConfig(configFile = "WEB-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml", configName = "MyEndpoint")
public class MyEndPoint implements IMyEndPoint {
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml used:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
       <deployment>
              <dependencies>
                     <module name="org.apache.cxf" export="true"/>
                     <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true"/>
                     <module name="org.apache.ws.security" export="true"/>
              </dependencies>
       </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Dependency declared in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
       <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.9</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure that this is exactly the same problem or root cause as the question, but hopefully it may help someone.

In my case, I ran into the exception when attempting to call a WebService secured using WS
Security. When running this inside JBoss 7.2 on Windows, the NAMESPACE_ERR exception was occurring before the intialization was complete, and the result was my outgoing calls did not contain the security information in the SOAP header, which was causing the calls to fail.

In the `org.apache.xml.security.stax.config.Init` class, I confirmed that the SAXParser was failing when trying to parse the file `wss/wss-config.xml` in the jar `wss4j-ws-security-stax-2.2.2.redhat-00002.jar`. More specifically, this file includes the file `security-config.xml` in the jar `xmlsec-2.1.2.redhat-00001.jar`, and it is actually when parsing this included file that the exception occurred. I confirmed this by modifying `wss/wss-config.xml` to not include `security-config.xml`, and this resolved the issue.

I ran the code that parses those files outside of JBoss. This ran successfully. After much investigation trying to determine the difference, I found that JBoss is effectively hijacking the XMLReaderFactory using its module class `__redirected.__XMLReaderFactory`, and creating its own instance of XMLReader that is used to parse the included file. Specifically, the instance that it was creating and using to parse the included file `security-config.xml` was created without the namespace aware feature. Because of this, the declaration at the top of that file

```
xmlns="http://www.xmlsecurity.org/NS/configuration"
```

was causing the exception, since the parser thinks this is overriding the default XML namespace of `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`.

My solution was to create a file `META-INF/services/org.xml.sax.driver` in our deployment telling JBoss' XMLReaderFactory which instance to create. I put in this file

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
```

which is the default implementation used outside of JBoss (the class that Java's SAX parsing library will create by default), and importantly, will enable the namespace feature when a new instance is created.